# MySQL: How to allow remote connection to mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL Community Edition 5.5 on my local machine and I want to allow remote connections so that I can connect from external source.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable remote MySQL connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380797/enable-remote-mysql-connection)

Comment: If you happen to using DigitalOcean, you may try to use `sudo mysql_secure_installation`. FYI.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code. Off topic.

Comment: @EJP why? honest question out of curiosity

Answer (score 882, accepted):

That is allowed by default on MySQL.

What is disabled by default is remote `root` access.  If you want to enable that, run this SQL command locally:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And then find the following line and **comment it out** in your `my.cnf` file, which usually lives on `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on Unix/OSX systems. In some cases the location for the file is /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf).

If it's a Windows system, you can find it in the MySQL installation directory, usually something like `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\`   and the filename will be `my.ini`.

Change line

```
 bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
 #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

And restart the MySQL server ([Unix/OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/282115/how-to-restart-mysql), and [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972434/restart-mysql-server-on-windows-7)) for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I did that ( grant privileges ) but still can't connect . and I'm using windows os I can't find my.cnf

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the location of the my.cnf file on Windows.

Comment: Ok so I've added the binnd-address = 127.0.0.1 at the end of the file and I've tried to connect using navicat from external host and I get 10060 error

Comment: Hmm, you don't need to add it.  Like my answer said, you need to comment it out, not add it.  There's one in there by default, so you'd need to find that, and comment it out by prefixing it with #

Comment: Hmm , in \MYsql Server 5.5\ there's only 1 ini file called my-default.ini and the only line without the # is this : sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

Comment: Ah ...done it seems that my other pc was blocking the access..thanks btw

Comment: this answer works perfect. thnx @mjuarez - 

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: What am I doing wrong if the GRANT results in Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)?

Comment: Thanks it worked... i did not require to do bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment: it does not work i follow all the steps , i'm using windows 8 , and no line for  bind-address was founded in the My.ini 
i always get the same error

Comment: @Oussaki which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: You might also have to open port 3306 in the Windows firewall (inbound rule for TCP).

Comment: I found you have to restart to mysql service after changing bind address.

Comment: I think this is also should be after granting "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

Comment: Only commenting out `bind-address` didn't work for me. Either `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` or `bind-address = <server_ip>` works.

Comment: When following this series of steps and use my password in place, I get an error that says "Password has should be a 41-digit hexadecimal number"  How do I get MySQL to accept my plain password and generate the hex for me?\ What is going wrong here? Tried using SET old_passwords = 0;

Comment: @BrandonS. you might have a typo. Take a look at this: https://lists.mysql.com/mysql/204753

Comment: That didn't really help. Double checked everthing. No typo. I ended up having to actually enter the Hash value of the password, which I got by using SELECT password('mypassword'). (http://knowmysql.blogspot.com/2013/09/mysql-grant-password-error-error-1372.html)

Comment: To those looking for the `my.cnf` file and not finding a `bind-address` directive in it, note that in my case (MySQL version 14.14 on Ubuntu 16.04.2) the location for the file was `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Comment: 'password' should be replaced with the users actual password... for any noobs like me.

Comment: I follow and run command but mysql return ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY '*****' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1``` . What should I do?

Comment: Plus, I use (brew) mysql version 8.0.12

Comment: @HàLink for mysql 8 check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409788/mysql-8-create-new-user-with-password-not-working

Comment: If there's a firewall installed, one should open the port on the firewall: `sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp` and finally `sudo service ufw restart`.

Comment: How to reverse back?

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is necessary?

Comment: My.ini on Windows is in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\ (At least with version 8.0)

Comment: mysql workbench doesn't work for Windows 7, it just can't connect. I tried Navicat under window 7 and worked.

Comment: Note that [MySQL 8 removed](https://ma.ttias.be/mysql-8-removes-shorthand-creating-user-permissions/) the one-liner for creating a user and granting permissions to it!

Comment: I am getting the error : mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'StackOverflowSolution' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'StackOverflowSolution' WITH GRANT OPTION' at line 1    How to fix this error? Mine is MySQL community edition 8 on Windows 11

Answer (score 57):

After doing all of above I still couldn't login as `root` remotely, but Telnetting to port `3306` confirmed that `MySQL` was accepting connections.

I started looking at the users in MySQL and noticed there were [multiple root users](https://serverfault.com/questions/235593/mysql-log-shows-3-root-users-2-without-passwords-why) with different passwords.

```
select user, host, password from mysql.user;
```

So in `MySQL` I [set all the passwords for root](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/) again and I could finally log in remotely as `root`.

```
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') where User='root';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: This is correct. While following steps in other answers, user accounts with empty password seem to be created. So you need to add passwords for them.

Comment: I needed to combine the accepted answer with this one and then everything worked properly.

Comment: SQL for 5.7 and above ```update user set authentication_string=password('YOUR_PASSWORD') where user='root';```

Comment: The accepted answer sets the password and worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, much like @James, I had to combine this with the accepted answer to fix.

Answer (score 50):

Just a note from my experience, you can find configuration file under this path `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

(I struggled for some time to find this path)

Comment: This is highly dependent on what distribution you are using. Best way is to just search for it: `sudo find /etc -iname 'mysql*.cnf'`

Comment: I appreciate the 'find' command. I'm new to command line, so it is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I struggled hours editing the /etc/mysq/conf.d/mysql.cnf untill I found this unswer.

Comment: On Centos 7: find /etc -iname 'my*.cnf'

Comment: This was helpful! Couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: seem root cant access in remote . Although change `localhost` to %

Answer (score 33):

In my case I was trying to connect to a remote mysql server on cent OS. After going through a lot of solutions (granting all privileges, removing ip bindings,enabling networking) problem was still not getting solved.

As it turned out, while looking into various solutions,I came across iptables, which made me realize mysql port 3306 was not accepting connections.

Here is a small note on how I checked and resolved this issue.

- Checking if port is accepting connections:

```
telnet (mysql server ip) [portNo]
```

- Adding ip table rule to allow connections on the port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

- Would not recommend this for production environment, but if your iptables are not configured properly, adding the rules might not still solve the issue. In that case following should be done:

```
service iptables stop
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 31):

All process for remote login. Remote login is off by default.You need to open it manually for all ip..to give access all ip

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Specific Ip

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'your_desire_ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

then

```
flush privileges;
```

You can check your User Host & Password

```
SELECT host,user,authentication_string FROM mysql.user;
```

Now your duty is to change this

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

You can find this on

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

if you not find this on there then try this

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

comment in this

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Then restart Mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Now enjoy remote login

Answer (score 19):

Please follow the below mentioned steps inorder to set the wildcard remote access for MySQL User.

> (1) Open cmd.
>
> (2) navigate to path C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.X\bin and
>   run this command.
>
> **mysql -u root -p**
>
> (3) Enter the root password.
>
> (4) Execute the following command to provide the permission.
>
> **GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY
>   'PASSWORD';**
>
> USERNAME: Username you wish to connect to MySQL server.
>
> IP: Public IP address from where you wish to allow access to MySQL
>   server.
>
> PASSWORD: Password of the username used.
>
> IP can be replaced with % to allow user to connect from any IP
>   address.
>
> (5) Flush the previleges by following command and exit.
>
> **FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**
>
> **exit;**
>   or **\q**

[image]

Comment: After doing it, my root still have access denied. What have I missed?

Comment: You can try with your local system IP Address instead of % in the 4th step. It should work. % means any IP Address.

Answer (score 10):

I had to this challenge when working on a **Java Project** with **MySQL** server as the database.

**Here's how I did it**:

First, confirm that your **MySQL** server configuration to allow for remote connections. Use your preferred text editor to open the MySQL server configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Scroll down to the **bind-address** line and ensure that is either **commented out** or replaced with `0.0.0.0` (to allow all remote connections) or replaced with **Ip-Addresses** that you want remote connections from.

Once you make the necessary changes, save and exit the configuration file. Apply the changes made to the MySQL config file by restarting the MySQL service:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Next, log into the MySQL server console on the server it was installed:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your **mysql user password**

Check the **hosts** that the user you want has access to already.  In my case the user is `root`:

```
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "root";
```

This gave me this output:

```
+-----------+
| host      |
+-----------+
| localhost |
+-----------+
```

Next, I ran the command below to grant the `root` user remote access to the database named `my_database`:

```
USE my_database;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';
```

**Note**: `%` grants a user remote access from all hosts on a network. You can specify the Ip-Address of the individual hosts that you want to grant the user access from using the command - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'Ip-Address' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';`

Afterwhich I checked the **hosts** that the user now has access to.  In my case the user is `root`:

```
SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "root";
```

This gave me this output:

```
+-----------+
| host      |
+-----------+
| %         |
| localhost |
+-----------+
```

Finally, you can try connecting to the MySQL server from another server using the command:

```
mysql -u username -h mysql-server-ip-address -p
```

Where **u** represents **user**, **h** represents **mysql-server-ip-address** and **p** represents **password**. So in my case it was:

```
mysql -u root -h 34.69.261.158 -p
```

Enter your **mysql user password**

You should get this output depending on your **MySQL** server version:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.7.31 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

**Resources**: [How to Allow Remote Connections to MySQL](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-remote-connection)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 10):

Close comment at link /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1  =>>  #bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Change the hostname so that all machines can access it, run this SQL command locally:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='%' WHERE Host='localhost' AND User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Restart service:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Open port mysql:

```
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

Answer (score 7):

If your MySQL server process is listening on 127.0.0.1 or ::1 only then you will not be able to connect remotely. If you have a `bind-address` setting in `/etc/my.cnf` this might be the source of the problem.

You will also have to add privileges for a non-`localhost` user as well.

Comment: Weird, how could your server be "listening" on another IP besides `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: @Pacerier 127.0.0.1 is only bound to the loopback interface. External connections will not work. A system will often have multiple network interfaces, each of which needs to be bound to specifically, or you can use the bind-all 0.0.0.0 address.

Answer (score 7):

If you installed MySQL from `brew` it really does only listen on the local interface by default. To fix that you need to edit `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` and change the `bind-address` from `127.0.0.1` to `*`.

Then run `brew services restart mysql`.

Comment: For my ubuntu 16.04.4 server, the bind-address setting is in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: This is not just using brew, any MySQL will have this default setting, to only allow local connections.

Answer (score 5):

Just F.Y.I
I pulled my hair out with this problem for hours.. finally I call my hosting provider and found that in my case using a cloud server that in the control panel for 1and1 they have a secondary firewall that you have to clone and add port 3306.  Once added I got straight in..

Comment: This sounds very specific to your situation.  I'm not an endless source of knowledge on networking, but are you sure this solution applies well to this problem?

Comment: I've had this issue too. Common with cloud hosted servers,

Comment: I had the same issue. This helped me.

Answer (score 4):

For whom it needs it, check firewall port 3306 is open too, if your firewall service is running.

Comment: Just realized that disabling Windows Firewall entirely was not enough too. I found I need disable my antivirus (Eset Endpoint Security). Now I can bring back Windows Firewall after adding a exception in my AV for mysqld-nt.exe

Answer (score 4):

If `mysqld` has a [bind address](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) set to a loopback/local address (e.g. `127.0.0.1`), the server will not be reachable from remote hosts, because a loopback interface cannot be reached from any remote host.

Set this option to `0.0.0.0` (`::` for IPv4+6) to accept connections from any host, or to another externally-reachable address if you want to only allow connections on one interface.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address)

Answer (score 3):

This blog [How to setup a MySQL server on Local Area Network](https://medium.com/@kasunsiyambalapitiya/how-to-setup-a-mysql-server-on-local-area-network-lan-c3c5012c7d6b) will be useful in setting up a `MySQL` from scratch

Comment: @Kokodoko I am happy it did :)

Answer (score 3):

MySQL 8 no longer allows you to create a user using the GRANT command. You need to create the user first.

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2):

And for OS X people out there be aware that the bind-address parameter is typically set in the launchd plist and not in the my.ini file. So in my case, I removed `<string>--bind-address=127.0.0.1</string>` from `/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mariadb.plist`.

Comment: Alternative location for the plist file: `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Answer (score 2):

Enabling remote root access can be dangerous. It would be preferable if you were to set up user accounts with more restrictive permissions. The following three steps should do it.

1. Ensure that the line starting with `bind-address ...` is at least commented out in your my.ini or my.cnf file. If it doesn't exist, move on.
   You can find this file in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` on Windows.
2. Afterwards, check that the user account you are establishing the connection with does not have `localhost` in the Limit to Hosts Matching field. While it isn't recommended, you can instead put `%` in that field for testing purposes. You can do this by opening a local connection to the server with MySQL Workbench, then going to Server>Users and Privileges from the menu bar and finding the user account you want to connect with.

The "Limit to Hosts Matching" field is what disallows you to connect non-locally. I.e. it limits the accepted connections to a pattern of IP addresses. Ideally, you should be accessing the MySQL server from a static IP address or subnet, so that you can be as restrictive as possible.

3. Obviously, your firewall should allow the MySQL Server application to communicate over the port you want. The physical networking equipment in between you and your server should allow communication on the port you want to connect with. (port 3306 typically)

Comment: port (3306) forwarding in the router helped me thank you.

Comment: Sometimes it's really just the simple things :^) Glad I could help.

Comment: Adding the right user with the right IP address in mSQL Workbench.., it was so simple.
No command line. No restart of mySQL. It works right away.

Answer (score 1):

some times need to use **name of pc on windows**

**first step)** put in config file of mysql:

> mysqld.cnf SET bind-address= 0.0.0.0

(to let recibe connections over tcp/ip)

**second step)** make user in mysql, table users, with **name of pc on windows** propierties,  **NOT ip**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Check remote server grant permission to Wildcard access to port 3306:

> sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

It should NOT be same like this:

> mysqld    23083       mysql   21u  IPv4 145900142      0t0  TCP
> `127.0.0.1`:3306 (LISTEN)

In this case, we need to update /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf or /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf with:

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1 --> 0.0.0.0

And then restart mysql "sudo service mysql restart"

In order to test mySQL connection from a client:

> nc -vz <host_address> 3306

Comment: Make sure that open port 3306 accessible via:  sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT #mysql