# Create user with no privileges in RDS for MySQL fails, error 1396

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

After going through all the motions to create a database instance on AWS using the RDS tool I've been able to access the database through MySQL Workbench. I've used the master username and password chosen on creation of the instance.

However I wish to create new users who have restricted privileges and can't seem to achieve this without returning an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eED0S.jpg).

[image]

As one can see I've tried it through workbench as well as gitbash and recieved the linked errors.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArTim.jpg) an image of the interface. I've tried creating a user with zero privaleges and still the same error messages. **I know the privilege `SUPER` can't be granted in RDS**.  Creating the user fails, without any grants.

The database I'm trying to create new users for is empty and I'm currently using the default VPC. Not sure if either of those affect this.

Any help is appreciated!

I haven't set up any EC2 instance or BD security group, not sure if that's also relevant (Even though I intend to setup in a VPC).

Comment: @ceejayoz based on current information, I don't see this as a duplicate.  Unfortunately, we only had a link to a screenshot of the error rather than the text, in-line.  I've inlined that image.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have the reputation yet to post images inline.

Comment: Oh, Stack Overflow, how you disappoint me sometimes.  This was clearly not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't be related to security groups.  Your RDS instance isn't actually aware of them -- they only control access to the host running the RDS instance at the TCP layer, in the AWS network.

Regarding your issue -- I *think* what you'll find is that you somewhere along the line actually did manage to create the user:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'stackoverflow'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'stackoverflow'@'%';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'stackoverflow'@'%'

mysql> CREATE USER 'stackoverflow';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'stackoverflow'@'%'

mysql>
```

To see the user accounts on the server `SELECT * FROM mysql.user;`.

Note that user `'stackoverflow'` and `'stackoverflow'@'%'` refer to the same user, where `@'%'` means the user's login privilege is not restricted by source IP address or host *by MySQL* (it can and will still be restricted by the security group settings, as I'll show in some more detail, below).

The `mysql.user` table contains all of the accounts the server knows about.  This table (and [several other grant tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant-table-structure.html)) *can* be manipulated manually, but it's best to use the `GRANT`, `REVOKE`, `CREATE USER`, and `DROP USER` statements.

---

Potentially helpful later... if you do set up the security group in such a way that you can't connect to the server (because your source IP address isn't permitted) this will not cause any behavior change on the part of MySQL -- your connection will simply time out, never actually reaching the server, regardless of username and password.

It's a common error you'll see *entirely* too many people making (including here on SO) to start dinking around with permissions on the server, when they encounter this specific problem -- don't do that -- the problem is *always* one of *network connectivity* if you see exactly the following behavior:

```
$ mysql -h my-rds-with-security-group-too-restrictive.jozxyqk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my-rds-with...' (110)
```

`ERROR 2003` can mean several things... but the money is at the end of the line.  That code `(110)` at the end is telling you you're never reaching the server -- it's *not* a permissions issue, if you see this exact code code.  Look it up:

```
$ perror 110
OS error code 110:  Connection timed out
```

(Linux error code `110` shown; Mac is probably the same code, since I suspect it's a standard POSIX error code, while Windows makes up their own.  I believe it's `10060` on Windows that conveys the same meaning.)

Comment: Really appreciate the help. Yeah the user has been created and I can see it in this table. I also installed HeidiSQL and was able to see a couple of users I'd created while receiving errors in Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a duplicate of this question: [Creating A New MySQL User In Amazon RDS Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198367/creating-a-new-mysql-user-in-amazon-rds-environment)

> mysql -u [your_master_username] -p -h YOURRDSENDPOINT.rds.amazonaws.com
>
> CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
>   GRANT SELECT ON [your_database].[some_table] TO 'jeffrey'@'%';

Comment: Doesn't it seem like this is what OP *is* doing in the [screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/VQpgxUp.jpg) of the error?

Comment: Tried everything in this thread with no success. That OP wasn't have the same problems as me.